# How can I make this JQuery and HTML, per-row specific?

Tags: html, jquery

[image: Image showing the issue]In CB UserList the form appears multiple times (one for every record) and the below code is expected to produce the submit button and the modules to show/hide for every record that appears on the list separately. When a user makes a selection on the first row, everything works fine but only for the first row. Button and module divs show/hide properly on the first row (first record) only. The problem is that as the code is now, the selection on the first row is applied to all rows and the show/hide appears to all rows simultaneously. I need it to appear in each row separately, like when I select the first or any row, the other rows to remain unchanged unless I select them. Maybe I need something like parent/child/siblings relation for the button and the modules?

My html is as follows

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <select name="test" class="form-control">
            <option label="Please select" selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
            <optgroup label="test1" style="font-weight: bolder;">
               <option label="1a" value="UserSubmit, free"></option>
               <option label="1b" value="6"></option>
               <option label="1c" value="3"></option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="test2" style="font-weight: bolder;">
               <option label="2a" value="O24"></option>
               <option label="2b" value="O12"></option>
               <option label="2c" value="O6"></option>
               <option label="2d" value="O2"></option>
            </optgroup>
         </select>
      </div>
      <div id="free">{loadmoduleid 240}</div>
      <div id="button"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="somevalue" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-primary UserSubmit" /></div>
      <div id="6">{loadmoduleid 234}</div>
      <div id="3">{loadmoduleid 235}</div>
      <div id="O24">{loadmoduleid 236}</div>
      <div id="O12">{loadmoduleid 237}</div>
      <div id="O6">{loadmoduleid 238}</div>
      <div id="O2">{loadmoduleid 239}</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").on('change', function () {
        var x = this.selectedIndex;

        if (x == "1") {
            $(".UserSubmit").show();
            $("#free").show();
            $("#6").hide();
            $("#3").hide();
            $("#O24").hide();
            $("#O12").hide();
            $("#O6").hide();
            $("#O2").hide();
        } else if (x == "2") {
            $(".UserSubmit").hide();
            $("#free").hide();
            $("#6").show();
            $("#3").hide();
            $("#O24").hide();
            $("#O12").hide();
            $("#O6").hide();
            $("#O2").hide();
        } else if (x == "3") {

more ifs until x == "7"

        } else {
            $(".UserSubmit").hide();
            $("#free").hide();
            $("#6").hide();
            $("#3").hide();
            $("#O24").hide();
            $("#O12").hide();
            $("#O6").hide();
            $("#O2").hide();
        }
    });
    $(".UserSubmit").css("display", "none");
    $("#free").css("display", "none");
    $("#6").css("display", "none");
    $("#3").css("display", "none");
    $("#O24").css("display", "none");
    $("#O12").css("display", "none");
    $("#O6").css("display", "none");
    $("#O2").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question a little? I tried your code on JS Fiddle, and it seems to work just fine. Only one row at the time is shown. Or do you want it to be a toggle? So when, on row is selected, it is toggled either on or off?

Comment: I do not understand this: _the "show/hide" rules appear to all rows. I need it to appear in each row separately._

Comment: @Sami and Marc, you are both correct, I should have included it in my question. I need it to toggle in each row separately. As it is now, when I toggle one, the other rows toggle too.

Comment: I use this in a Community Builder userlist. In their forum the answer was "Your show/hide JS isn't per-row specific is why that's happening. You need UserSubmit to be per-row specific to prevent that..." "...usually you'd just make that a sibling or a child of a sibiling of your select element. That'd let you do things like $( this ).siblings( '.UserSubmit' ) to only toggle the immediate sibling of the select element."

Comment: It's best to make a [minimal repeatable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put here or on codepen.io, jsfiddle.net or codesandbox.io

Comment: @Grzegorz T You are very correct but the problem is that I can't reproduce the issue on JS Fiddle as I don't know how to display the CB's userlist and from the code above the issue is not clear unless you have used CB userlist before to understand what I mean.

Comment: So basicly, this is not an HTML/jQuery -related issue, but it has something to do with Community Builder specificly?

Comment: It is not a Community Builder issue if that's what you mean. I need somehow to define the per-row specific command between JQuery and HTML. That is what I am trying to figure out how to...  This called my attention and I think has a smell of solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780491/nested-divs-change-function-and-show-hide-siblings-children-and-parents) Maybe I should somehow make the button and module divs nested and play with siblings/parent relation? A bit lost at the moment...

Comment: @GalanopD If these are not sensitive data, make a print screen and insert a photo with a description here. Then it will be easier for us to see this problem.
Inserting consists in dragging and lowering the photo to the place where the cursor is positioned.

Comment: @Grzegorz T I have uploaded an image that shows clearly (I believe...) the case.

Comment: @GalanopD I added a solution and it looks like the picture shows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I scribbled something, I hope I understood correctly and this code reflects what you wanted.

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelectorAll('select');
selectElement.forEach(select => {
  const colElement = select.parentNode.closest('.col-md-6');

  const withoutFormGroup = (Array.from(colElement.children).filter(child => child.id !== select.id));

  // hidden all elements
  withoutFormGroup.forEach(child => {
    child.style.display = 'none';
  });

  // show selected element
  select.addEventListener('change', function() {
    const indexSelected = this.selectedIndex;
    const indexValue = this.value;

    // show selected element
    withoutFormGroup.forEach((child, index) => {
      child.style.display = child.id === indexValue ? 'block' : 'none';

      // if selected element is 1 then show
      // first and second element
      if (indexSelected === 1 && (index === 0 || index === 1)) {
          child.style.display = 'block';
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col-md-6>*+* {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.row+.row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="test" class="form-control">
          <option label="Please select" selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
          <optgroup label="test1" style="font-weight: bolder;">
            <option label="1a" value="UserSubmit, free"></option>
            <option label="1b" value="6"></option>
            <option label="1c" value="3"></option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="test2" style="font-weight: bolder;">
            <option label="2a" value="O24"></option>
            <option label="2b" value="O12"></option>
            <option label="2c" value="O6"></option>
            <option label="2d" value="O2"></option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="free">{loadmoduleid 240}</div>
      <div id="button">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="somevalue" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-primary UserSubmit" />
      </div>
      <div id="6">{loadmoduleid 234}</div>
      <div id="3">{loadmoduleid 235}</div>
      <div id="O24">{loadmoduleid 236}</div>
      <div id="O12">{loadmoduleid 237}</div>
      <div id="O6">{loadmoduleid 238}</div>
      <div id="O2">{loadmoduleid 239}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="test" class="form-control">
          <option label="Please select" selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
          <optgroup label="test1" style="font-weight: bolder;">
            <option label="1a" value="UserSubmit, free"></option>
            <option label="1b" value="6"></option>
            <option label="1c" value="3"></option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="test2" style="font-weight: bolder;">
            <option label="2a" value="O24"></option>
            <option label="2b" value="O12"></option>
            <option label="2c" value="O6"></option>
            <option label="2d" value="O2"></option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="free">{loadmoduleid 240}</div>
      <div id="button">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="somevalue" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-primary UserSubmit" />
      </div>
      <div id="6">{loadmoduleid 234}</div>
      <div id="3">{loadmoduleid 235}</div>
      <div id="O24">{loadmoduleid 236}</div>
      <div id="O12">{loadmoduleid 237}</div>
      <div id="O6">{loadmoduleid 238}</div>
      <div id="O2">{loadmoduleid 239}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="test" class="form-control">
          <option label="Please select" selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
          <optgroup label="test1" style="font-weight: bolder;">
            <option label="1a" value="UserSubmit, free"></option>
            <option label="1b" value="6"></option>
            <option label="1c" value="3"></option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="test2" style="font-weight: bolder;">
            <option label="2a" value="O24"></option>
            <option label="2b" value="O12"></option>
            <option label="2c" value="O6"></option>
            <option label="2d" value="O2"></option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="free">{loadmoduleid 240}</div>
      <div id="button">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="somevalue" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-primary UserSubmit" />
      </div>
      <div id="6">{loadmoduleid 234}</div>
      <div id="3">{loadmoduleid 235}</div>
      <div id="O24">{loadmoduleid 236}</div>
      <div id="O12">{loadmoduleid 237}</div>
      <div id="O6">{loadmoduleid 238}</div>
      <div id="O2">{loadmoduleid 239}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's best if you put this code from `id="free"` to `id="02"` in an additional div with some class because currently I rely on the `"col-md-6"` class and it can be disastrous ;)
And most importantly, I haven't been using jquery for a few years, so the code is in plain js ;)

I can see that you are relying on the id, remember that there can only be one id the same on a page. You cannot duplicate them. It's best to use data attributes.

**EDIT**

In one of the threads you wrote "... list of hundreds or thousands of users ..." And you did not mention that in the description;). I modified the solution and hide the data using css, not js. If we do not do this, before js starts working, all elements that should not be visible will be visible on the website.

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelectorAll('select');

selectElement.forEach(select => {

  const modules = select.parentNode.nextElementSibling;

  // show selected element
  select.addEventListener('change', function() {
    const indexSelected = this.selectedIndex;
    const indexValue = this.value;

    // show selected element
    [].slice.call(modules.children).forEach((child, index) => {
      child.style.display = child.dataset.id === indexValue ? 'block' : 'none';

      // if selected element is 1 then show
      // first and second element
      if (indexSelected === 1 && (index === 0 || index === 1)) {
        child.style.display = 'block';
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: top;
  border: 1px solid red;
  gap: 30px;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.modules>* {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="test" class="form-control">
          <option label="Please select" selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
          <optgroup label="test1" style="font-weight: bolder;">
            <option label="1a" value="UserSubmit, free"></option>
            <option label="1b" value="6"></option>
            <option label="1c" value="3"></option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="test2" style="font-weight: bolder;">
            <option label="2a" value="O24"></option>
            <option label="2b" value="O12"></option>
            <option label="2c" value="O6"></option>
            <option label="2d" value="O2"></option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modules">
        <div data-id="free">{loadmoduleid 240}</div>
        <div data-id="button">
          <input name="submit" type="submit" value="somevalue" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-primary UserSubmit" />
        </div>
        <div data-id="6">{loadmoduleid 234}</div>
        <div data-id="3">{loadmoduleid 235}</div>
        <div data-id="O24">{loadmoduleid 236}</div>
        <div data-id="O12">{loadmoduleid 237}</div>
        <div data-id="O6">{loadmoduleid 238}</div>
        <div data-id="O2">{loadmoduleid 239}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="test" class="form-control">
          <option label="Please select" selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
          <optgroup label="test1" style="font-weight: bolder;">
            <option label="1a" value="UserSubmit, free"></option>
            <option label="1b" value="6"></option>
            <option label="1c" value="3"></option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="test2" style="font-weight: bolder;">
            <option label="2a" value="O24"></option>
            <option label="2b" value="O12"></option>
            <option label="2c" value="O6"></option>
            <option label="2d" value="O2"></option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modules">
        <div data-id="free">{loadmoduleid 240}</div>
        <div data-id="button">
          <input name="submit" type="submit" value="somevalue" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-primary UserSubmit" />
        </div>
        <div data-id="6">{loadmoduleid 234}</div>
        <div data-id="3">{loadmoduleid 235}</div>
        <div data-id="O24">{loadmoduleid 236}</div>
        <div data-id="O12">{loadmoduleid 237}</div>
        <div data-id="O6">{loadmoduleid 238}</div>
        <div data-id="O2">{loadmoduleid 239}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select name="test" class="form-control">
          <option label="Please select" selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
          <optgroup label="test1" style="font-weight: bolder;">
            <option label="1a" value="UserSubmit, free"></option>
            <option label="1b" value="6"></option>
            <option label="1c" value="3"></option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup label="test2" style="font-weight: bolder;">
            <option label="2a" value="O24"></option>
            <option label="2b" value="O12"></option>
            <option label="2c" value="O6"></option>
            <option label="2d" value="O2"></option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modules">
        <div data-id="free">{loadmoduleid 240}</div>
        <div data-id="button">
          <input name="submit" type="submit" value="somevalue" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-primary UserSubmit" />
        </div>
        <div data-id="6">{loadmoduleid 234}</div>
        <div data-id="3">{loadmoduleid 235}</div>
        <div data-id="O24">{loadmoduleid 236}</div>
        <div data-id="O12">{loadmoduleid 237}</div>
        <div data-id="O6">{loadmoduleid 238}</div>
        <div data-id="O2">{loadmoduleid 239}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added a `modules` class in which I hide elements using css. Well, these elements have a `data-id` not an `id`. It should be correct now.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Following your example, will I need to replicate the HTML for every row? If yes this will be impossible as the userlist might be a list of hundreds or thousands of users. Maybe I haven't understood correctly

Comment: The most important thing is that there are always two `free` and `button` id elements behind the element with the `form-group` class, the rest does not matter.

Comment: I really don't have words to thank you, it works more than ok! It wouldn't be possible for me to implement that! Many thanks for your time and your patience.

Comment: Remember to use the second example. It is optimized.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow exclude the following div from the code? `.container-inner > div:not(.cbFieldsContentsTab)`. Tried a couple of things but not succesfully...

Comment: As I understand it, you want to prohibit the possibility of selecting a specific item from select. If so, it is not better to remove this element using the class e.g. `.hidden { display: none; }` ;) I added an example https://jsfiddle.net/tomik23/mbvg0f9e/

Comment: And if you want to show an item but can't click on it, just add `disabled` to options.
`<option selected="true" disabled>Abc</option>`

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to help without the code. Create a minimal working example and place for example on https://codepen.io
And there, describe what you want to happen. And most importantly, create a new thread because here it is a mess.

Comment: Ok @Grzegorz you are correct. I will do some cleaning here and then create a new working example

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toggle()` method on the div whose id matches the selected option.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("select").on('change', function () {
            var target = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-toggle-target');
        $('#' + target).toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select name="test" class="form-control">
                <option label="Please select" selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>
                <optgroup label="test1" style="font-weight: bolder;">
                    <option label="1a" value="value1a" data-toggle-target="6"></option>
                    <option label="1b" value="value1b" data-toggle-target="3"></option>
                    <option label="1c" value="value1c" data-toggle-target="024"></option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="test2" style="font-weight: bolder;">
                    <option label="2a" value="value2a" data-toggle-target="012"></option>
                    <option label="2b" value="value2b" data-toggle-target="06"></option>
                    <option label="2c" value="value2c" data-toggle-target="02"></option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="free">{loadmoduleid 240}</div>
        <div id="button"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="somevalue" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-primary UserSubmit" /></div>
        <div id="6">{loadmoduleid 234}</div>
        <div id="3">{loadmoduleid 235}</div>
        <div id="O24">{loadmoduleid 236}</div>
        <div id="O12">{loadmoduleid 237}</div>
        <div id="O6">{loadmoduleid 238}</div>
        <div id="O2">{loadmoduleid 239}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you don't need the `value` attribut on the options anywhere else, I suggest you replace the `value` of each option with the corresponding id's of the divs and you can simplify you jQuery to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").on('change', function () {
        var target = $(this).val();
        $('#' + target).toggle();
    });
});
```

Sadly, this won't work if you hit the same option twice in a row, since the `<select>` selected item doesn't change. You could use `click` event on the `<select>`, but that fires twice (first when you open the dropdown, second when selecting the value) so you would need to filter out the first event. `click` event on `<option>` doesn't work, at least on Chrome.